# how to get the opportunityproduct fields in opportunity object in validation rule

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, validation-rule

I want to create a validation rule at "Opportunity" Standard Object to validate the following.

Opp record Type – sample 
And Stage not equal to ‘Pending Approval’
 Product or product code(item number) ends with -22 or -23 or -24

Then you it should give the following error message. 
When requesting samples for 130 Lumen parts, stage should be pending approval.

Can any one help me out how to get the "product code" field in opportunity object in a validation rule.

I Shall appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you using standard product code or have you created a custom field to capture product code?

Comment: @AmitBangad:we are use both the standard as well as custom codes.

Comment: Ive suggested an approach, you can try that out and use the product codes as you want.

Comment: @AmitBangad:When the user of  profile names:'Custom Marketing Users 10K 25K', 'Customer Service User' are creating a record it should throw an error .So how to include them

Comment: I modified the answer to include this.

Comment: Can u please help me on this  . The user should not have an option to change the stage name again (i.e from "pending approval to request submitted,etc").So how can i restrict this

Comment: Nikkey - Google 'salesforce prevent change of stage' for a long list of solutions

Answer (score 1):

Step1 : 
Create a custom field on 'Opportunity Product' 
Type - **Number (1,0)**
Name - "Lumen Part Code Count"
Step2:
Create a Workflow rule on Opportunity Product with Criteria "**OR(RIGHT(Product2.ProductCode,3) == '-23',RIGHT(Product2.ProductCode,3) == '-24', RIGHT(Product2.ProductCode,3) == '-25')**" and Everytime record is created.
Write a field update that updates "Lumen Part Code Count" to 1 (Formula Value   **1**)
Step3:
 Create a RollUp Summary field on Opportunity.Name - "Lumen Part Code Sum"
Select Count and "Only records meeting certain criteria should be included in the calculation"
Criteria- Lumen Part Code Count = 1
Step 4 : 
Write your validation rule with criteria

```
 AND(
OR(
$Profile.Name = "Custom Sales User",
$Profile.Name = "Custom Marketing Users 10K 25K"
),
NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Pending Approval")),
RecordTypeId == '18DigitRecordTypeIdofSample',
Lumen_Part_Code_Sum__c > 0
)
```

Mention your error message there.

Cheers,

Comment: Alternative to this excellent answer would be to make the Opportunity product field a checkbox entitled `is_lumen_product__c` and have the WF populate it to true.  The essence of your solution is you are working around the inability of RSF to use criteria on the detail record that refer to cross object fields (Product2.xxx fields in this use case)

Comment: @crop1645:Now their is another clause needed to be added as " the 2 profile users should not have an option to change the stage name again (i.e from "pending approval to request submitted,etc").So how can i restrict this"